# What if the app server is offline when the client sends a new registration token?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If my Android client app receives a new registration token, it will send this new token via FCM to the app server. If the app server has the new token, he can send messages to the client app.

If the client is offline, FCM will store the message, until the client goes online and then send the message forward to the client. So far, so good.

**BUT**, if the client wants to send a new registration token, but the app server is offline, FCM doesn't store the token in order to send them to the app server as soon as he goes online.

Is there an existing mechanism (apart from a timer mechanism, which polls the reg token periodically), that an app server gets the registration token, until it changes its status from unreachable to reachable?

Comment: no mechanism as far as I know, you need to make sure the App Server is ALWAYS online. What I've resorted to is the app checks if theres a new token in my onResume and uploads to server all the time, cant risk having tokens that are not upto date

Comment: Ensure that your app server can't go down. If your backend doesn't work than your app doesn't work. I don't understand what you are asking. Avoid the problem entirely by ensuring the necessary uptime, there are strategies to increase it much at possible. Don't optimize for the rare corner case where for whatever reason your backend doesn't work. The much more likely problem is your client being offline or being in a network that is slow or one that can't reach your backend. Have you dealt with these issues in your app? Then you really don't have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Manny264 in the comments section, there is no mechanism or API as of the moment for this scenario. And since the issue here is because of an App Server that is expected to be handled on your end, I think it is also pretty much expected that you handle this scenario by yourself.

I would suggest checking the response you receive when attempting to send the registration token to your App Server, if it fails, re-attempt the request again on a later time, but you already mentioned that you do not want anything like a *timer mechanism* and such.

What you could possibly do is make use of the [Topics Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), have a *universal* topic that all users automatically subscribe to (in this scenario, the client app is able to successfully subscribe), and if ever your App Server is down for a period of time, upon getting online again, make use of the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances) to retrieve the list of subscribed tokens, then check and compare if there are any new tokens that isn't saved in your App Server yet.

Choice is up to you though. I think it'd be easier if you just implement a retry mechanism on the Client App side.